# Seperate api and web in route

Tags: node.js, express

Trying to separate api and web route:

route/index.js

```
var api = function () {
    router.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
       ...
    });

    return router;
}

var web = function () {
    router.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
       ...
    });

    return router;
}

module.exports = {
    api: api,
    web: web
};
```

app.js

```
var indexAPI = require('./app/routes/accounts').api;
var indexWeb = require('./app/routes/accounts').web;

app.use('/api/index', indexAPI);
```

but it didn't route successfully.

Comment: It's a typo? var wen = function () {... Maybe it should be web

Comment: I change it, no it is not that problem, api is not accessible too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change it to and it is working:

```
var api = (function () {
    router.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
       ...
    });

    return router;
})();

var web = (function () {
    router.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
       ...
    });

    return router;
})();

module.exports = {
    api: api,
    web: web
};
```